# Obj-C scope / equivalent of C# IDisposable, 'using', or C++ auto variables?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to create obj c objects that are tied to scope, so the object knows when it's entering / exiting scope.

This is an ARC environment.

The goal is to create some logging utilities that can easily produce logs that encapsulate processes, like this:

```
onHttpRequest {
    deduce encoding - found UTF-8!
    parsing xml took 0.08 seconds
    unknown request found... sending error.
    sendingResponse took 0.02 seconds.
} (0.10 seconds)
```

This has been easy in C++ and C# in the past. Now I'm learning obj-c, and can't think of a way to do this in any clean way.

In C++, this is easy using `auto` variables:

```
struct ScopedLogMessage
{
    ScopedLogMessage(std::string msg) { debugPrint(indentStr + msg + newline); indent ++; }
    ~ScopedLogMessage() { indent --; debugPrint(indentStr + "}" + newline); }
}

void onHttpRequest()
{
    ScopedLogMessage x("onHttpRequest");
    debugPrint("deduce encoding ...");
    debugPrint("more stuff ....");
}
```

Or in C#, with `IDisposable` and `using(){}` blocks:

```
class ScopedLogMessage : IDisposable
{
    public ScopedLogMessage(string msg) { debugPrint(indentStr + msg + newline); indent ++; }
    public void Dispose() { indent --; debugPrint(indentStr + "}" + newline); }
}

static void onHttpRequest()
{
    using(ScopedLogMessage x = new ScopedLogMessage("onHttpRequest"))
    {
        debugPrint("deduce encoding ...");
        debugPrint("more stuff ....");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do a similar thing in objective-C?

Comment: Yes; edited to specify that

Comment: Any reason not to use Objective-C++ so you can keep using the C++ technique?

Comment: My personal reason is that I don't know anything about Obj-C++, and this whole environment is pretty new to me. Certainly if XCode presented me with the option of creating an "Objective C++ Class" I would take it more seriously. I just don't see anything about Obj-C++ anywhere ... is it in common use in a typical OSX/XCode environment?

Comment: Just as Objective-C simply adds language features on top of C, so Objective-C++ adds the same features on top of C++. By default, any file with an extensions of `.mm` is compiled as Objective-C++. You can also direct Xcode to compile any particular file as Objective-C++, overriding what it would otherwise choose based on file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ARC variables are retained and released automatically by the compiler when they are out of the scope, so the code would be something like this:

```
NSLog(@"Logging at indent level 0");
{
    ScopedLogMessage* log1 = [[ScopedLogMessage alloc] initWithMessage:@"Begin nested operations"];
    [log1 debugLog:@"Logging at indent level 1"];
    {
        ScopedLogMessage* log2 = [[ScopedLogMessage alloc] initWithMessage:@"Another level of nested operations" parentLog:log1];
        [log2 debugLog:@"Logging at indent level 2"];
    }
    [log1 debugLog:@"Logging at indent level 1 again"];
}
NSLog(@"Logging at indent level 0 again");
```

And the output will be:

```
Logging at indent level 0
Begin nested operations {
    Logging at indent level 1
    Another level of nested operations {
        Logging at indent level 2
    }
    Logging at indent level 1 again
}
Logging at indent level 0 again
```

The code for the ScopedLogMessage class:

*ScopedLogMessage.h*:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ScopedLogMessage : NSObject
- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message;
- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message parentLog:(ScopedLogMessage*)parentLog;

- (void)debugLog:(NSString*)message;
@end
```

*ScopedLogMessage.m*:

```
#import "ScopedLogMessage.h"

@interface ScopedLogMessage ()
@property ScopedLogMessage* parentLog;
@property int indent;
@end

@implementation ScopedLogMessage

- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self debugLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ {", message]];
        self.indent = 1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString *)message parentLog:(ScopedLogMessage *)parentLog {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.parentLog = parentLog;
        self.indent = parentLog.indent;
        [self debugLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ {", message]];
        self.indent++;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.indent --;
    [self debugLog:@"}"];
}

- (void)debugLog:(NSString*)message {
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSString* indentString = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:self.indent * 4 withString: @" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@%@", indentString, message);
#endif
}

@end
```

As you see, the `dealloc` method is the key, equivalent to C# `Dispose`. Without ARC you would be forced to release the log and call `[super dealloc]` on the `dealloc` method .

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps a lot -- but I'll get a compiler warning about `logMessage` being unused. Is there a way to suppress this warning only for `ScopedLogMessage` objects?

Comment: I believe that ARC is allowed to release an object after the last time it's used, which may be before it goes out of scope. The test should have another log inside the braces (at `// Do something fancy!`) to make sure the "Exiting…" message comes after that.

Comment: Hi @KenThomases I wasn't comfortable with the answer too, so I created a full solution avoiding the static 'indent' variable (awful for multithreading) and performing the log inside the class to avoid being disposed before time.

Comment: Very interesting! Actually I think I might use a thread-local stack to keep track of the "parents" without having to pass them in, which is annoying in error-prone.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :D